# I want to change html class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to change class on hover 
to fa-angle-down

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#home i').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('fas fa-angle-down');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fas fa-angle-up');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#home" id="home">Services <i id="angle" class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
```

script

Comment: What is your issue? If you place an alert in the hover function, does it ever get called?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With pure JavaScript, you can just use the [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property to toggle the classes like this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("home");
x.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  this.children[0].classList.add("fa-angle-down");
  this.children[0].classList.remove("fa-angle-up");
})
x.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  this.children[0].classList.add("fa-angle-up");
  this.children[0].classList.remove("fa-angle-down");
})
```

```css
.fa-angle-up:after{content:"up!";}.fa-angle-down:after{content:"down!";}
```

```html
<a href="#home" id="home">Services <i id="angle" class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
```

---

**N.B.** The *up* and *down* text is just for demonstrating how the JavaScript works.

Answer (score 0):

When the mouse goes over, you are **adding** `fa-angle-down` and when it goes out, you are **removing** `fa-angle-up`.

If you want to swap them, you need to **add** one and **remove** class **each** time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#home i').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
    }, function () {
        $(this).addClass('fa-angle-up').removeClass('fa-angle-down');
    });
});
```